# Data type mismatch in criteria expression while updating password field

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, oledb

This is my Select & Update code for OLEDB DB.

I am getting a Data type mismatch in criteria expression error whilst changing the Password field value.

All four fields are set to Long Text datatype.

**Update Query**

```
con = Class1.dbconn
cmd = New OleDbCommand("Update User_details set User_ID ='" & TextBox1.Text & "', User_Name='" & TextBox2.Text & "', [Password]='" & TextBox3.Text & "' where Sno='" & Label4.Text & "'", con)
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
MessageBox.Show("User Details Updated")
```

**Select Query**

```
cmd = New OleDbCommand("select * from User_details where User_ID='" & TextBox1.Text & "'", con)
Dim dr As OleDbDataReader
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
If dr.Read Then
    Label4.Text = dr("Sno").ToString
    TextBox2.Text = dr("User_Name").ToString
    TextBox3.Text = dr("Password").ToString
    TextBox2.Text = TextBox2.Text.Replace("  ", "")
    TextBox3.Text = TextBox3.Text.Replace("  ", "")
    dr.Close()
End If
```

Comment: What is `Longtext`? Do you mean `Memo`? Use Parameters to build the queries ([OleDbCommand.Parameters.Add()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbparametercollection.add)). Also, see [INFO: OleDbType Enumeration vs. Microsoft Access Data Types](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/320435/info-oledbtype-enumeration-vs-microsoft-access-data-types).

Comment: Show us your table create statement. If using Sql Server Management Studio, right click the table and choose Script table as create, to New Window. Also, as @Jimi stated, you should consider using parameters instead of inline sql. This code is open to a sql injection attack. If this is for learning only, okay. After you get it working, go learn the right way. You should NEVER NEVER NEVER do this in a production app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep your database objects local so you can control when they are closed and disposed. `Using...End` Using blocks take care of this for you even if there is an error. The Using blocks demonstrated here take care of both the connection and the command. Note the comma after the connection line.

Always use `Parameters`. Not only does it make your command text easier to read and write (without all the quotes, double quotes and ampersands) but it protects your database from the destruction of Sql injection. When you are using the `OleDb` provider it is essential that order that the parameters appear in the command text match the order they are added to the parameters collection. Unlike Sql Server, Access pays no attention to the names of the parameters; only the order.

Notice that the connection is not opened until right before the `.Execute...` and is closed (with the `End Using`) directly after. Connections are precious resources. I used a `DataTable` instead of a `DataReader` in the `SelectUser` sub so I could close the connection before updated the user interface. In the `UpdatePassword` sub the connection is closed before showing the `MessageBox`. After all the end user could have gone to lunch and there would be your connection flapping in the breeze.

As far as the type mis-match check the links provided by @Jimi and then check your database to see if the `OleDbType` matches.

```
Private Sub UpdatePassword()
    Using con As New OleDbConnection("Your connection string"),
            cmd As New OleDbCommand("Update User_details set User_ID = @ID, User_Name = @Name, [Password]= @Password Where Sno= @Sno;", con)
        With cmd.Parameters
            .Add("@ID", OleDbType.LongVarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text
            .Add("@Name", OleDbType.LongVarChar).Value = TextBox2.Text
            .Add("@Password", OleDbType.LongVarChar).Value = TextBox3.Text
            .Add("@Sno", OleDbType.LongVarChar).Value = Label4.Text
        End With
        con.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
    MessageBox.Show("User Details Updated")
End Sub

Private Sub SelectUser()
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using con As New OleDbConnection("Your connection string"),
        cmd As New OleDbCommand("select * from User_details where User_ID= @ID;", con)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", OleDbType.LongVarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text
        con.Open()
        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
    End Using

    If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        Dim row As DataRow = dt.Rows(0)
        Label4.Text = row("Sno").ToString
        TextBox2.Text = row("User_Name").ToString
        TextBox3.Text = row("Password").ToString
        TextBox2.Text = TextBox2.Text.Replace("  ", "")
        TextBox3.Text = TextBox3.Text.Replace("  ", "")
    End If
End Sub
```

Finally, you should NEVER store passwords as plain text. They should be salted and hashed. I will leave it to you to research how to do this.